# Defining color of 3D points plot based on distance in R

Tags: r, colors, plot

Suppose I generate some three-dimensional Gaussian samples and I plot these with plot3D. I want to color the points depending on their distance to the center of the cloud. By this I mean that I want to give them a color between *white* (= far away from the center) and *somecolor* (very close to the center).

I am aware of functions like colorRamp and colorRampPalette but I'm not sure how to use these in this specific situation. Any help would be appreciated!

**Edit** This is what I have so far:

```
library(rgl)

#generate two 3D point clouds
cloud1 <- rmnorm(100,mean=c(1,1,1),varcov=diag(.25,3)) 
cloud2 <- rmnorm(75, mean=c(3,3,3),varcov=diag(.5,3))

plot3d(cloud1,box=F)
points3d(cloud2,col="red")
```

The resulting plot:

[image: wut]

But now I want to let points that are further away from the center to be less black/red.

Comment: Do you have some example code? You could also try to rank your values and than when plotting just add something like color=DF$rank.

Comment: Apologies, I've added code and a plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like that:

```
cloud1 <- rmnorm(100,mean=c(1,1,1),varcov=diag(.25,3))
# for an euclidean distance but a manhalobis distance should be more appropriated
aux <- colSums((t(cloud1)-colMeans(cloud1))^2) 
col1 <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "white"))
# i used quantiles but equal interval could be used to
cols1 <- col1(11)[findInterval(aux, quantile(aux, seq(0,1,0.1)), right=T)]
# with equal interval
cols1 <- col1(11)[findInterval(aux, seq(min(aux), max(aux), le=10))]
plot3d(cloud1,box=F, col=cols1)
```

HTH